# word cloud counting double words instead of one

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to do a word cloud with matplotlib in python and instead of counting single words like "will" its counting two like "i will". I have looked at the word cloud documentation and there doesnt seem to be anything that produces this, could my input be causing this?

my code looks like the following:

```
fields = ['comments']

text= pd.read_csv('comments.csv', usecols=fields)

stopwords = ["https", "RT"] + list(STOPWORDS)

print(' '.join(text['comments'].tolist()))

wordcloud = WordCloud(stopwords=stopwords, background_color="white").generate(' '.join(text['comments'].tolist()))

plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation (https://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/generated/wordcloud.WordCloud.html) states:

> collocations: bool, default=True
>
> Whether to include collocations (bigrams) of two words. Ignored if using generate_from_frequencies.

You may need to include collocations=False in the parameters to WordCloud.

Comment: thanks a lot, this was the problem